# Как перехватить клавишу Enter для QTextEdit?

Tags: macos, qtcreator, qt, c++

Как перехватить нажатие клавиши Enter для виджета **QTextEdit**? Проект создан в Qt Creator. Пытаюсь реализовать это следующим образом:

**mytextedit.h**

```
#ifndef MYTEXTEDIT_H
#define MYTEXTEDIT_H
#include <QTextEdit>
class myTextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myTextEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * e);
signals:
public slots:
};
#endif // MYTEXTEDIT_H
```

**mytextedit.cpp**

```
#include "mytextedit.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
myTextEdit::myTextEdit(QWidget *parent) :
    QTextEdit(parent)
{
}
void myTextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if(e->key()==Qt::Key_Enter)
    {
        qDebug()<< "Ok";
    }
}
```

но без результатно - программа не входит даже в метод **keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)**, при клавишной активности.

Comment: В метод вообще не заходит?

Comment: Нет - даже в метод *myTextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)* не заходит.

Comment: Я сейчас проверил, у меня в метод keyPressEvent заходит (если у Вас не заходит - проверьте входит ли в конструктор, может быть у вас создается не Ваш класс, а QTextEdit - я не знаю как Вы создаете объект, я через дизайнер формы).
При нажатии на Enter, у меня, код равен не Qt::Key_Enter, а Qt::Key_Return.

Comment: @hokum2004, да и вправду - и в конструктор не заходит. Проект мой лежит здесь https://github.com/derkode/ForvoClient.git .Ничего не пойму

Comment: @hokum2004, покажи свой код... как ты сделал...

Comment: derkode, https://github.com/hokum2004/QTextEditorTest1 единственное, что я использовал Qt 4.8, попозже попробую поставить Qt 5, которую, видимо, использовал ты и проверить. О результатfх напишу.

Comment: Похоже глюк Qt, а точнее теневой сборки. Отключи теневую сборку в свойства проекта "Projects", флаг "Shadow build". И удали файл ui_dialog.h.
После чего перестрой проект и у тебя в myTextEdit не правильный конструктор, раскомментируй правильныЙ, а то что ты дописывал удали.

Answer (score 3):

Хм, должно работать:

```cpp
class TextEdit: public QTextEdit
{
protected:
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* e) {
        QTextEdit::keyReleaseEvent(e);
        qDebug() << "keyReleaseEvent" << e;

        if (e->key() == Qt::Key_Return || e->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) {
            qDebug() << "keyReleaseEvent Enter";
        }
    }
};
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
keyReleaseEvent QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, 1000004, 0, """", false, 1) 
keyReleaseEvent Enter 
keyReleaseEvent QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, 1000005, 20000000, """", false, 1) 
keyReleaseEvent Enter 
keyReleaseEvent QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, 44, 0, ""d"", false, 1) 
keyReleaseEvent QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, 47, 0, ""g"", false, 1)
```